# angular/node.js POST for payumoney integration

Tags: angularjs, node.js, payumoney

I'm using angular/node.js stack for payumoney integration.

On the angular side, an order is placed using $http.post to a route endpoint at the server side (node.js) as follows:

```
$http.post('/placeOrder',order).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
      //handle responses on client side
      console.log("Successfully POSTED to payment gateway");
      window.location = "https://test.payu.in/_payment";
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Error in posting");
   });
```

The actual heavy lifting is done on the node.js (server side):

```
router.post('/placeOrder', function(req, res, next){

hash_data = MERCHANT_KEY+'|'+txnid+'|'+amount+'|'+productinfo+'|'+firstname+'|'+email+'|'+udf1+'|'+udf2+'|'+udf3+'|'+udf4+'|'+udf5+'||||||'+SALT;

var data = querystring.stringify({

      'key': MERCHANT_KEY,
      'txnid': txnid,
      'amount': amount,
      'productinfo': productinfo,
      'firstname': firstname,
      'email': email,
      'phone': phone,
      'surl': SUCCESS_URL,  
      'furl': FAILURE_URL,
      'curl': FAILURE_URL,
      'hash': hash,
      'service_provider': SERVICE_PROVIDER
      //'salt': SALT
    });

    //POST options
    var POST_OPTIONS = {
        hostname: PAYU_BASE_URL,
        port: 443,
        path: '/_payment',
        method: 'POST',
        //json: true,
        agent: false,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            //'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
            'Content-Length': data.length
        }
    };

    var resp_status = "";

    var req = https.request(POST_OPTIONS, function(response) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log("body: " + chunk);
            resp_status = 200;
            res.json(chunk);
        });
        response.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log("Got error: " + err.message);
            resp_status = 500;
            return res.send(err);
        });
    });
    req.end(data);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as the POST doesnt seem to work using this approach. While debugging on the browser through the network tab, I always see:

Request URL:https://test.payu.in/_payment
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Also, the test payment page (https://test.payu.in/_payment) shows:
"Error Reason
One or more mandatory parameters are missing in the transaction request."

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

How did I implement this..

1. Use Jquery and create a Form
2. Use sha512 to create hashcode. (bower install js-sha512)

```
 var hashString = this.merchantKey+'|'+ options.uid +'|'+ options.totalPrice + '|'+'options.uid + '|' +
        options.recipient_name + '|'+ options.email +'|||||||||||'+ this.merchantSalt ;

    var hash = sha512(hashString);





    var key1 = $('<input></input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "key").val("merchantKey");

    var key2 = $('<input></input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "txnid").val(options.uid);

    var key3 = $('<input></input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "amount").val(options.totalPrice);

    var key4 = $('<input></input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "productinfo").val(options.uid);

    var key5 = $('<input></input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "firstname").val(options.recipient_name);

    var key6 = $('<input></input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "email").val(options.email);

    var key7 = $('<input></input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "phone").val(options.phone);

    var key8 = $('<input></input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "surl").val("http://192.168.43.121/payment/success");

    var key9 = $('<input></input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "furl").val("http://192.168.43.121/payment/error");

    var key10 = $('<input></input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "hash").val(hash);

    var key11 = $('<input></input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "service_provider").val("payu_paisa");


    var form = $('<form/></form>');

    form.attr("id", "payuform");

    form.attr("action", this.payumoneyLink );

    form.attr("method", "POST");

    form.attr("style", "display:none;");

    form.append(key1, key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9,key10, key11);


    $("body").append(form);

    // submit form

    form.submit();
```

This is my first answer on StacksOverflow. Hope it helps!

Comment: Please do not publish your email address in your answers

Answer (score 0):

As per the browser network tab which you have mentioned,

`Request URL:https://test.payu.in/_payment Request Method:GET Status Code:200 OK`

This means PayU is getting called with GET request instead of POST request somehow. PayU accepts data as a POST request only.

`Also, the test payment page (https://test.payu.in/_payment) shows: "Error Reason One or more mandatory parameters are missing in the transaction request."`

This is due to GET request. I have faced similar situation in my JSF based application wherein I was sending all parameters correctly but as a GET request. Later on when I switched to POST, the error got resolved automatically.

For information about sending POST request from angular, check below link.

https://www.devglan.com/angular/payumoney-integration-angular

Answer (score -1):

NOTE: If input type is hidden, angularjs has some issue connecting model and view. So please take a note of that. txnid and hash I am getting from AJAX get call so I had to bind it in seperate variable from scope.

Angular code is staright forward, just populate the variables.
One more thing to remember as of today, if your account is not active then you need to use test salt/key provided by their customer support:

```
MID : 4934580
Key : rjQUPktU
Salt : e5iIg1jwi8
Authorization : y8tNAC1Ar0Sd8xAHGjZ817UGto5jt37zLJSX/NHK3ok=
Test Card : 5123456789012346
Expiry : 05/20                                                                     
CVV : 123
```